# Instagram Decline public_content permission

Tags: instagram-api

I have created mobile app and used Instagram api for searching users and feeds of users.but They have declined the public_content permission. How can I solve this issue.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the documentation.

> **My submission was rejected but it was a valid use case. What should I do?**
>
> A common reason for rejecting a submission is that we do not have
>   enough information to make an assessment of your app. This can happen
>   if your submission was too short, if it missed important information,
>   if you did not provide a good screencast, your website is not working,
>   etc. Before you submit for review again, make sure to provide a long
>   and clear explanation of what your app does and how you use every
>   permission. Make sure also to provide a video screencast and to follow
>   all our Platform Policies.
>
> **What should I write in the submission?**
>
> The submission should be long enough for us to understand exactly what
>   your app does and why you need the permissions you are asking for. If
>   your submission is too short or does not explain all parts of your
>   integration, then we may not be able to understand and approve your
>   app. For example, your submission should explain what does your app or
>   company do, which of the approved use cases your integration falls
>   into, who will be using your app, how do your user authenticate with
>   your app, how you use the API to power your integration, how does your
>   product use the data acquired from Instagram, etc.
>
> **What should I show in the video screencast?**
>
> The video screencast is a very important part of a submission and
>   cannot be omitted. Please make sure that the video clearly shows how
>   your application works, including any Instagram login experience and
>   the usage of every permission you are requesting. Since your app may
>   still be in sandbox mode, you can use data from sandbox users to
>   showcase the integration.